# bucle infinito al imprimir con HasMorePages C#

Tags: c#

recien comienzo con C# y estoy aprendiendo a como generar e imprimir un documento, pero me encuentro estancado a la hora de querer imprimir mas de una pagina me hace un bucle infinito y no encuentro alguna manera plactica en internet para solucionarlo, intente de algunas varias manera pero me sigue haciendo un bucle y hasta el momento este es mi ultimo intento.
Estoy utilizando Win Forms

Este es mi codigo

```
var printedLines = 0;

public static void printDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev, List<Detail> details)
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= details.Count - 1; i++)
  {
    nombre = details[i].nombre;
    ev.Graphics.DrawString(nombre, font10, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(200, altura += 0, 260, 15));
    ++printedLines;
  }
  if (printedLines > 4) // numero de ejemplo
  {
     ev.HasMorePages = true;
  } else
  {
     ev.HasMorePages = false;
  }
```

agradezco cualquier ayuda que me ofrezcan, gracias

Comment: Por qué dices que es un bucle infinito? El `for` parece estar bien estructurado y va desde cero hasta `Count - 1`. Lo que sí es posible, es que `details` sea `null`, y tengas un `NullPointerException` al momento de llamar a `details[i].nombre`. Estás seguro que ese no es el caso?

Comment: Bueno digo que es un bucle porque cuando lo guardo en PDF para pruebas, una ventana me muestra un conteo de páginas y comienza a generar un sin fin de páginas cuando solo me debe de generar dos, y sobre lo de que details sea `null` no sería por ahí pues si tiene valores, ya que cuando género un documento menor a 4 detalles me genera el documento perfectamente

Comment: Esto es Win forms, WPF, UWP ????

Comment: Oh es verdad, disculpa @Yussef, es Win forms